# How to calculate perpendicular distance between a line and a point when using coordinates (latitude & longitude)

Tags: java, math, geometry, trigonometry

I want to calculate the perpendicular distance between line and a point. 
LinePointA(latitude,longitude)-(48.294483,11.568453)
LinePointB(latitude,longitude)-(48.283479,11.838929)
PointC(latitude,longitude)-(48.561846,11.733314)
Here AB is the line and C is the point.
Expected distance as per google maps is 59.36 km 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The answer is entirely dependent on whether you will only be considering lines and points close enough to be considered flat, or whether it needs to work for any set of valid global coordinates?

Comment: Yes. Need to work with valid global coordinates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [barefoot](https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot) -- open source Java library for geometric operation with Earth coordinates.

Here is a solution for your problem  -- https://github.com/bmwcarit/barefoot#spatial-search-and-operations

If you want to dive deeper and understand math, look [this](http://biodiversityinformatics.amnh.org/open_source/pdc/documentation.php)

Comment: I tried adding barefoot to maven <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.bmw-carit/barefoot -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.bmw-carit</groupId>
    <artifactId>barefoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.1</version>
</dependency>
But it shows error "Missing artifact com.bmw-carit:barefoot:jar:0.1.1".

Comment: Did you add http://nexus.onebusaway.org/nexus/content/repositories/public/ repository to pom?

Comment: I did not do that. And it worked after adding it. Thank you @Kirill Liubun